# Trying to call update of OneStepCheckout in Magento returns url error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I am using the following code to try to update the payment methods of OneStepCheckout in magento however it does not seem to be working, looking at the problem in firebug shows the url in red.

```
jQuery(document).ready(get_separate_save_methods_function('/onestepcheckout/ajax/set_methods_separate', true));
```

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share what is the response code? Is it 404 or something else? Also if mod_rewrite in not enable you may need try the next url "/index.php/onestepcheckout/ajax/set_methods_separate"

Comment: you are calling the method that returns you a method and to execute this you should evoke it by adding () at the end as well. YOu should use full url that magento gives you